# Java Scanner not behaving correctly?

Tags: java, string, string-formatting, java.util.scanner

I have the following Code Snippet in my project:

```
 public void addText(String s){
    Scanner scan;
    int newInt = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(s.indexOf('\t') + 1 + 1));
    //find insertion point
    String temp = "";
    scan = new Scanner(text);
    int prev = 0;
    while(scan.hasNextInt() && newInt > scan.nextInt()){
        temp += text.substring(prev, text.indexOf('\n')) + "\r\n";
        prev = text.indexOf('\n') + 1;
    }
    text = temp + s + "\r\n" + text.substring(prev);
}
```

The goal of this is to insert a string into an existing string and keep it in a somewhat "numerical order".

The `String s` is a formatted string that looks like `"CityName\t\tSomeNumber"`. That code for `newInt` works (confirmed by debugging). What doesn't work is the `while` loop. Even when `text` has data in it, the `scan.hasNextInt()` fails.

For example, assume `text = "Charlestown\t\t9"`,`s = "Downville\t\t15"`. `newInt` gets assigned 15. The `while` loop should iterate once and end, since `15 > 9` (were organizing cities in ascending order of these numbers). But for some reason the Scanner returns false every time on the `scan.hasNextInt()`part of the condition statement.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Javadoc for `hasNextInt` says

> Returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be
>   interpreted as an int value in the default radix using the nextInt()
>   method. The scanner does not advance past any input.

Which means that if your next token is "Charlestown", this will return false.  You're going to have to read the name of the town from your scanner before you check `hasNextInt()`.